# Checking a users group memberships

Tags: windows, vbscript, dns

I've been working quickly on a little script so that I can set and remove networks drives or create folders depending on a persons group membership, it doesn't seem to work and there are no error messages, could do with a second pair of eyes, I'd really appreciate it!

```
DIM CHS
SET CHS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
SET CHSshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
SET CHSnetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

PRIVATE FUNCTION isMember( Group )
    SET netCHS = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Domain = netCHS.UserDomain
    User = netCHS.UserName
    isMember = false
    SET userCHS = GetObject("WinNT://" & Domain & "/" & User & ",user")
        FOR EACH Group in userCHS.Groups
            IF (Group.Name = GroupName) THEN
                isMember = true
        EXIT FOR
            END IF
    NEXT    
    SET userCHS = NOTHING
    SET netCHS = NOTHING
END FUNCTION

SET CHS = NOTHING

IF ( isMember("Domain Admins") = "True" ) THEN
    CHSnetwork.RemoveNetworkDrive "z:"
    WSript.Echo "CHSnetwork.UserName"
END IF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call

```
isMember("Domain Admins")
```

The function

```
PRIVATE FUNCTION isMember( Group )
```

picks up the parameter in the name `Group`. But you (re/mis-)use `Group` in

```
FOR EACH Group in userCHS.Groups
```

to loop over the `userCHS.Groups` and in

```
IF (Group.Name = GroupName) THEN
```

to get the `.Name` to compare with `GroupName`. Where does `GroupName` come from?. Try to change the function's header to

```
PRIVATE FUNCTION isMember( GroupName )
```

and consider to use `Option Explicit` to avoid such mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 0):

This VBS script will show all groups the user belong to:

```
Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oNetwork: Set oNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

Dim sUserName: sUserName = oNetwork.UserDomain & "/" & oNetwork.UserName
sUserName = InputBox("Windows User Name","Enter Windows User Name", sUserName)

If sUserName <> "" Then
    GetGroups
End If

Sub GetGroups
    Const ADS_READONLY_SERVER = 4
    Dim oGroup, oUser
    Dim oShell: Set oShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim sFolderPath: sFolderPath = GetFolderPath()
    Dim oNS: Set oNS = GetObject("WinNT:")
    Dim oList: Set oList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Dim sFilePath: sFilePath = sFolderPath & "\" & Replace(Replace(sUserName,"\","-"),"/","-") & "_groups.txt"

    Set oUser = oNS.OpenDSObject("WinNT://" & sUserName, "", "", ADS_READONLY_SERVER)
    For Each oGroup In oUser.groups
        oList.Add oGroup.Name
    Next

    oList.Sort()

    Dim oLog: Set oLog = fso.CreateTextFile(sFilePath, True)
    For Each sItem in oList
        oLog.Write sItem & vbCrLf
    Next

    oLog.Close
    oShell.Run sFilePath
End Sub

Function GetFolderPath()
    Dim oFile 'As Scripting.File
    Set oFile = fso.GetFile(WScript.ScriptFullName)
    GetFolderPath = oFile.ParentFolder
End Function
```